# Compute this numerical series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hypergeometric-function, geometric-series

i would like to find a formula that is true for $n \geq 1$ for that :
$\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{k! \times k}$
I already tried many things like telescoping the sum or symetrising it but i cant find anything at all..
It makes me think about $e^x$ series but its not really it and n doesn't go to infinity so it doesn't works.
I take any hint !

Comment: Strirling's approximation might be useful here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
\sum _{k=1}^{n}{\frac {{n}^{k}}{k!\,k}}=n\;
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(1,1;\,2,2;\,n)}-{\frac {{n}^{n+1}\;
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(1,n+1;\,n+2,n+2;\,n)}}{\Gamma \left( n+2 \right) 
 \left( n+1 \right) }}
$$
You will probably not find anything simpler.